# Excel VBA: How to copy and paste an embedded object?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I copy an embedded object form Excel file to a specified folder? I have worked it out till copying.

```
Sub temp()
Dim cal As Object
Set cal = Sheet6.OLEObjects(1)
Dim savepath As String
savpath = ThisWorkbook.path & "\"
'Paste code here----
End Sub
```

Comment: May I know what OLEObject you are trying to paste?

Comment: it's a ocx file....i have a date picker (calendar - mscal.ocx) in the excel that i'm using but this file is not present in every computer. so i'm automating the process of saving this file to windows/sys32 folder whenever the user uses the file for the first time

Comment: do you have a solution?

Comment: I am afraid not, copying itself might not be sufficient , you might have to register the control with admin rights onto the machine.